# statvfs unsupported filesystems

Tags: linux, filesystems

[It seems](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html) that POSIX 2008 permits `statvfs` to fail with the error ENOSYS (The filesystem does not support this call).

This error has been dropped in the [latest POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/statvfs.html) revision, though.

I was unable to find any information which filesystems would not support `statvfs`. Is this something I should worry about on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many old systems you might need to worry about.

You need to check whether the call to [`statvfs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/statvfs.html) fails or not — there are other reasons it could fail.  So, whether ENOSYS is one of the returned errors is largely immaterial; you probably use `strerror()` or one of its relatives to report the error.  The only difference with ENOSYS compared with, say, ELOOP is that there is no way to fix ENOSYS (without modifying the kernel so ENOSYS is no longer an appropriate response) whereas with ELOOP you might find a way to disentangle yourself from the loop of symlinks (but you might not bother to try).

Comment: You are right, I have to check the return value anyways. In the moment I am trying to understand if I can fail softly (warning) or have to fail hard (die), but this consideration is not subject of this question. The circumstance that neither me nor the user can easily fix ENOSYS is important to me only for that reason.

Comment: It depends on what you're going to do with the information you would like to get from the system call. My gut feel is that you might well decide to proceed as if everything was OK, perhaps with a warning that expected information wasn't available — or maybe you decide that whatever the user specified isn't suitable and give an appropriate error. You're probably unlikely to find a file system on a modern Linux box that doesn't support it anyway, so it's likely worrying about the improbable (a good thing to do, but only in moderation, and it's not a good idea to procrastinate too long over it).